# Doubly Linked List moving item to end java

Tags: java, list

I found this code for adding an item to the front of the linked list, but since I have a last node, it doesn't work quite right, so I changed it a tiny bit:

```
    public void moveToFront(String node) {

    DoubleNode previous = first;
    temp = first;

    while (temp != null) {
        if (node.equals(temp.item)) {
            //Found the item
            previous.next = temp.next;
            temp.next = first;
            first = temp;

            if (last.next != null) {
                last = last.prev;
                last.prev = previous;
            }

            return;
        }
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
```

The `if (last.next != null)` is asking if the original last was moved, and checking if the new last has the right links. Now I think it works properly for my code.

I'd like to implement this code, but for adding an item to the end. However, last just isn't right now. When calling `last.prev` it only gets the one item behind it, but `last.prev.prev` to infinity is the same item.

My idea was instead of working from first like in `moveToFront()`, I work from last, and step through each node backwards, but obviously that doesn't work when last doesn't work anymore.

```
public void moveToEnd(String node) {

DoubleNode previous = last;
    temp = last;
    System.out.println("last = " + last.prev.item);
    System.out.println("temp = " + temp.item);

    while (!temp.item.equals(first.item)) {

        if(node.equals(temp.item)){
            System.out.println("previous.prev = " + previous.prev.item);
        }

        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.prev;

        System.out.println("temp.prev = " + temp.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.prev.item);
    }
```

Here's how I implement my linked list:

```
public class LinkedListDeque {

public DoubleNode first = new DoubleNode(null);
public DoubleNode last = new DoubleNode(null);
public DoubleNode temp;
public int N;

LinkedListDeque() {
    first.next = last;
    last.prev = first;
}

private class DoubleNode {

    String item;
    int counter = 0;
    DoubleNode next;
    DoubleNode prev;

    DoubleNode(String i) {
        this.item = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: the moveToFront code does not work if the need you need to move is the first

Comment: I'm not moving first, I'm moving any node to first, so if I have 1,2,3, and I want to move 3 to first, the list would print 3,1,2

Comment: Yes, but if you pass the node as 1 i.e if you want to move "1 to first" the list should ideally remain the same but with your algorithm it breaks the list. 1.next will be pointing to 1

Comment: oh for sure, like I said I found this code, and I'm trying to make it work better. I already came across that fault, but I'm just focusing on dealing with last

Answer (score 1):

I found this example of a complete doubly linked list. It does not have an add to front method, but it is adding to the back of the linked list each time. Hopefully, it will help and give you a better idea of how this data structure is supposed to work and function. I would definitely test it first as it states in the [readme](https://github.com/halls7588/Data_Structures_in_15_Languages/blob/master/README.md) for this GitHub that none of the code has been tested.  [Sorce](https://github.com/halls7588/Data_Structures_in_15_Languages/blob/master/Java/Lists/Doubly_Linked_List/DoublyLinkedList.java)

```
/*******************************************************
 *  DoublyLinkedList.java
 *  Created by Stephen Hall on 9/22/17.
 *  Copyright (c) 2017 Stephen Hall. All rights reserved.
 *  A Linked List implementation in Java
 ********************************************************/
package Lists.Doubly_Linked_List;

/**
 * Doubly linked list class
 * @param <T> Generic type
 */
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    /**
     * Node class for singly linked list
     */
    public class Node{
        /**
         * private Members
         */
        private T data;
        private Node next;
        private Node previous;

        /**
         * Node Class Constructor
         * @param data Data to be held in the Node
         */
        public Node(T data){
            this.data = data;
            next = previous = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Private Members
     */
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int count;

    /**
     * Linked List Constructor
     */
    public DoublyLinkedList(){
        head = tail = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new node into the list with the given data
     * @param data Data to add into the list
     * @return Node added into the list
     */
    public Node add(T data){
        // No data to insert into list
        if (data != null) {
            Node node = new Node(data);
            // The Linked list is empty
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
                tail = head;
                count++;
                return node;
            }
            // Add to the end of the list
            tail.next = node;
            node.previous = tail;
            tail = node;
            count++;
            return node;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first node in the list matching the data
     * @param data Data to remove from the list
     * @return Node removed from the list
     */
    public Node remove(T data){
        // List is empty or no data to remove
        if (head == null || data == null)
            return null;

        Node tmp = head;
        // The data to remove what found in the first Node in the list
        if(equalTo(tmp.data, data)) {
            head = head.next;
            count--;
            return tmp;
        }

        // Try to find the node in the list
        while (tmp.next != null) {
            // Node was found, Remove it from the list
            if (equalTo(tmp.next.data, data)) {
                if(tmp.next == tail){
                    tail = tmp;
                    tmp = tmp.next;
                    tail.next = null;
                    count--;
                    return tmp;
                }
                else {
                    Node node = tmp.next;
                    tmp.next = tmp.next.next;
                    tmp.next.next.previous = tmp;
                    node.next = node.previous = null;
                    count--;
                    return node;
                }
            }
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        // The data was not found in the list
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the first node that has the given data
     * @param data Data to find in the list
     * @return Node First node with matching data or null if no node was found
     */
    public Node find(T data){
        // No list or data to find
        if (head == null || data == null)
            return null;

        Node tmp = head;
        // Try to find the data in the list
        while(tmp != null) {
            // Data was found
            if (equalTo(tmp.data, data))
                return tmp;
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        // Data was not found in the list
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the node at the given index
     * @param index Index of the Node to get
     * @return Node at passed in index
     */
    public Node indexAt(int index){
        //Index was negative or larger then the amount of Nodes in the list
        if (index < 0 || index > size())
            return null;

        Node tmp = head;
        // Move to index
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            tmp = tmp.next;
        // return the node at the index position
        return tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current count of the array
     * @return Number of items in the array
     */
    public int size(){
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a is equal to b
     * @param a: generic type to test
     * @param b: generic type to test
     * @return boolean: true|false
     */
    private boolean equalTo(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b) == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually see that part of the code, but if it's just adding an item to the end, that's sometimes I've got already. In my case I'm trying to move an already existing item in the list to the end

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your `moveToFront()` method. It does not work for if `node == first`. If the node that needs to be moved is the first node, you end up setting `first.next = first` which is incorrect. The below code should work

```java
    public void moveToFront(DoubleNode node) {

    DoubleNode previous = first;
    temp = first;

    while (temp != null && node != first) {
        if (node.equals(temp.item)) {
            //Found the item
            previous.next = temp.next;
            temp.next = first;
            first = temp;

            if (last.next != null) {
                last = last.prev;
                last.prev = previous;
            }

            return;
        }
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }
```

Now coming to `moveToLast()` the following code should work

```
public void moveToLast(DoubleNode node) {
    DoubleNode temp = first;
    DoubleNode prev = new DoubleNode(null);   //dummy sentinel node

    while (temp != null && node != last) {
         if (temp == node) {
              if (temp == first) first = temp.next;

              prev.next = temp.next;
              if (temp.next != null) temp.next.prev = prev;
              last.next = temp;
              temp.prev = last;
              last = temp;
              last.next = null;
              break;
         }

         prev = temp;
         temp = temp.next;
    }
}
```